# Copying Data from a Column of All Worksheets in an Excel file and Pasting it into one sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I need to copy the data from a specific column of all worksheets of an excel file and paste it on to specific sheet with each subjects' name as the first row of the column (which is also the sheet name) and their data underneath that.

The problem is that I get Run-time error '1004':

> Application-defined or object-defined error

at the line: `targetWs.Cells(2, subColumn).PasteSpecial x1PasteValues`

```
Sub Data()
'
' Data Macro

'assign varaible to subject worksheet and target worksheet
Dim subWs As Worksheet
Dim targetWs As Worksheet
'set subject sheet and target sheet
Set targetWs = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

'Loop through all worksheets
'not really sure if I'm doing this right

'Copy subject name; paste to target sheet
Rows(1).Insert
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
    Cells(1, i) = Sheets(i).Name
Next i

'Loop through all worksheets
'not really sure if I'm doing this right
For Each subWs In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    'Copy subject data; paste to target sheet
    subWs.Range("B2:B242").Copy
    targetWs.Cells(2, subColumn).PasteSpecial x1PasteValues
    subColumn = subColumn + 1
Next subWs

End Sub
```

Comment: subColumn = subColumn + 1  change  line  before  targetws.cells (....

Comment: Dy.Lee thank you, that fixed one problem, however now there is error "subscript out of range" on Set targetWs = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("BrAC") ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comment above, I'll try to make it clear what they meant.

***First***, you have a typo, `PasteSpecial x1PasteValues` should be `PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` (it's an "l" not "1").

***Second***, first time you enter the loop (`For Each subWs In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets`), since you haven't initialized `subColumn` to any value, it's `0`. so when you try to paste `targetWs.Cells(2, subColumn)`, the first time you enter the loop it's actually `targetWs.Cells(2, 0)`, since there is no column `0`, you get this "lovely" run-time error #1004.

Comment: Okay, thank you Shai Rado. However, now I get an error Object doesn't support this property or method error 438 on the same line as before ( targetWs.Cells(2, subColumn).PasteSpecial x1PasteValues ) ?

Comment: @AnnaLi is your worksheet's name "BrAC" ? if there's a spelling error you will get this error. Also, try to avoid using `ActiveWorkbook`, if this worksheet is located in the workbook where this code lies, use `ThisWorkbook` instead

Comment: Thank you, that was my own fault, sorry. now I get an error Object doesn't support this property or method error 438 on the same line as before ( targetWs.Cells(2, subColumn).PasteSpecial x1PasteValues ) ?

Comment: @AnnaLi did you modify your type error ? it need to be `xlPasteValues` (not `x1PasteValues`).

Comment: Shai Rado yes, in my actual code, I fixed that typo.

Comment: @AnnaLi  what is the value of subColumn when u get this error ?

Comment: the value of subColumn = 2 to start and then later as you can see in my code subColumn = subColumn + 1

Comment: @AnnaLi code works great on my hand, try restarting Excel, run a new clean workbook with only update code, with 2 sheets and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

Copy a range of each sheet

Note: This example use the function LastRow
This example copy the range A1:G1 from each worksheet.

Change the range in this code line

```
'Fill in the range that you want to copy
 Set CopyRng = sh.Range("A1:G1")
Sub CopyRangeFromMultiWorksheets()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim DestSh As Worksheet
    Dim Last As Long
    Dim CopyRng As Range

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Delete the sheet "RDBMergeSheet" if it exist
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RDBMergeSheet").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    'Add a worksheet with the name "RDBMergeSheet"
    Set DestSh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    DestSh.Name = "RDBMergeSheet"

    'loop through all worksheets and copy the data to the DestSh
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sh.Name <> DestSh.Name Then

            'Find the last row with data on the DestSh
            Last = LastRow(DestSh)

            'Fill in the range that you want to copy
            Set CopyRng = sh.Range("A1:G1")

            'Test if there enough rows in the DestSh to copy all the data
            If Last + CopyRng.Rows.Count > DestSh.Rows.Count Then
                MsgBox "There are not enough rows in the Destsh"
                GoTo ExitTheSub
            End If

            'This example copies values/formats, if you only want to copy the
            'values or want to copy everything look at the example below this macro
            CopyRng.Copy
            With DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "A")
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End With

            'Optional: This will copy the sheet name in the H column
            DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "H").Resize(CopyRng.Rows.Count).Value = sh.Name

        End If
    Next

ExitTheSub:

    Application.Goto DestSh.Cells(1)

    'AutoFit the column width in the DestSh sheet
    DestSh.Columns.AutoFit

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win002.htm

Comment: @ ryguy72 sorry I don't really understand what you are trying to do?